# What is the difference between the cryptography and encryption tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457356/encryption-in-sql-sqlite) is tagged with both [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) and [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography).

Looking at the description of the tags, it seems [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography) is intended to be a super-set of of [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption).  Is that accurate?

Should it be a tag synonym, or should they be applied to different types of questions?  If so, what sorts of questions should each be applied to?

My initial guess is that question should just have [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) applied to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography) is a super-set of [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) in much the same way that [java](/questions/tagged/java) might be considered a super-set of [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is a super-set of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).  There's nothing wrong with having both tags, as some experts in [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography) might not be following [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) or vice-versa, and they are not exact synonyms.

Comment: +1 and accept for convincing examples

Comment: The problem is that they're not used consistently.