# Cleanup cryptography related tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

We've accumulated quite a few tags related to crypto. Several are just useless, some are ambiguous, and some are lacking hyphens.

Which should we kill, merge or rename?

[cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography)

[encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption)

[decrypt](/questions/tagged/decrypt) - merge into [encryption]

[encrypted](/questions/tagged/encrypted) - merge into [encryption]

[public-key-encryption](/questions/tagged/public-key-encryption) - rename to asymmetric-encryption?

[encryption-asymmetric](/questions/tagged/encryption-asymmetric) - merge with [public-key-encryption](/questions/tagged/public-key-encryption)

[encryption-symmetric](/questions/tagged/encryption-symmetric) rename to symmetric-encryption?

[encryption-symetrical](/questions/tagged/encryption-symetrical) - merge into [encryption-symmetric](/questions/tagged/encryption-symmetric)

[cryptographichashfunction](/questions/tagged/cryptographichashfunction) - add hyphens

[transparentdataencryption](/questions/tagged/transparentdataencryption) - add hyphens

[two-way-encryption](/questions/tagged/two-way-encryption) - I dislike this tag

[encrypting-code](/questions/tagged/encrypting-code) - retag individually, probably to obfuscation

[digital-signature](/questions/tagged/digital-signature) - keep

[cryptographic-signature](/questions/tagged/cryptographic-signature) - merge with digital-signature

[electronic-signature](/questions/tagged/electronic-signature) - possibly merge with digital-signature. Might have a slightly different meaning, including digitalized normal signatures.

[cryptographic-signature](/questions/tagged/cryptographic-signature) - merge with digital-signature

[fileencryption](/questions/tagged/fileencryption)

[asymmetric](/questions/tagged/asymmetric) - vague, merge on case-by-case basic

[publickey](/questions/tagged/publickey) - perhaps merge into public-key-cryptography

[privatekey](/questions/tagged/privatekey) - a bit ambiguous sometimes used for the private half of an asymmetric key, sometimes for the key in a symmetric scheme

[secret-key](/questions/tagged/secret-key) - similar to private key

[shared-secret](/questions/tagged/shared-secret)

[secret](/questions/tagged/secret) - vague, kill

[hash-collision](/questions/tagged/hash-collision) - used both in a crypto and in a hashtable context

[saltedhash](/questions/tagged/saltedhash) - It's rare to salt hashes that aren't password hashes

[hashalgorithm](/questions/tagged/hashalgorithm) - vague, retag to [hash] or something more specific. Often used for .net's `HashAlgorithm` class

[password-hash](/questions/tagged/password-hash) - keep

[password-encryption](/questions/tagged/password-encryption) - often abused for cases where password-hashes should be used

[symmetric](/questions/tagged/symmetric) - retag to [encryption-symmetric] if encryption related. But some are symmetric-crypto but not symmetric encryption

[symmetric-key](/questions/tagged/symmetric-key) - retag to [encryption-symmetric] if encryption related

One issue: encryption vs. cryptography

For example there is public-key-cryptography aka asymmetric-cryptography (no tags) which includes encryption, authentication and signatures. But we only have tags for public-key-encryption. Similar problems with other symmetric crypto that isn't symmetric encryption.

Related question: [What is the difference between the cryptography and encryption tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115579/what-is-the-difference-between-the-cryptography-and-encryption-tags)

Comment: @BilltheLizard [encrypt] and [decryption] are already synonyms of [encryption], but [decrypt] isn't. I see little gain in having a separate tag for decryption. There may be minor differences, but in practice it just means that questions are randomly splattered over a several tags.

Comment: My mistake. Carry on.

Answer (score 3):

Current status of progress made:

- Burninated the [fileencryption](/questions/tagged/fileencryption) tag (replaced with [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) as necessary)
- Burninated [encrypting-code](/questions/tagged/encrypting-code) (replaced with [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) or [obfuscation](/questions/tagged/obfuscation) as necessary)
- Burninated [secret](/questions/tagged/secret)

(will edit in more as I make progress)

Answer (score 2):

- retagged all from [cryptographic-signature](/questions/tagged/cryptographic-signature)
- retagged all from [encryption-symetrical](/questions/tagged/encryption-symetrical)