# Should "decryption" tag be synonymous with "encryption"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I was surprised to find out that [decryption](/questions/tagged/decryption) and [decrypt](/questions/tagged/decrypt) are [marked as synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms) of [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption).

This seems wrong to me. Sure, such questions are all going to be about cryptography, but the words are *antonyms* in the English language so I don't think we should be lumping them together like this. The problems and errors users face when encrypting are different to those faced when decrypting.

Can anyone offer a counter-argument why this might be useful to have in place? If not, can we remove it?

Some example questions that would benefit from this split:

- [One block cipher decryption with an AES and long key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421016/one-block-cipher-decryption-with-an-aes-and-long-key)
- [Decrypt file in parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651907/decrypt-file-in-parts)
- [Decrypt AES128-encrypted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192451/decrypt-aes128-encrypted-data)
- [RSA decrypt with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236481/rsa-decrypt-with-java)
- [Decrypt TripleDES "Bad Data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626126/decrypt-tripledes-bad-data)

Comment: Can you give some example questions where [tag:decryption] would be better than [tag:encryption]?

Comment: @Stijn Sure, see edits above.

Comment: Most users can't tell if their issue is actually with encryption or decryption. Many of the "I can't decrypt" questions actually boil down to "I messed up encryption, so decryption can't work". These tags have the same experts as well, I don't want to check yet another tag. The [cryptography] vs. [encryption] split is already annoying enough.

Comment: @CodesInChaos A good counter-argument. Would you prefer we try and condense the tag space down even further then? Perhaps having most things synonymous with [tag:cryptography]? (*Note: I fear that reads sarcastically but I'm genuinely asking*).

Comment: The tagging between [cryptography] and [encryption] is a bit inconsistent. Since [cryptography] is a superset of [encryption], in theory every [encryption] question could be tagged [cryptography] as well. There is a related question [What is the difference between the cryptography and encryption tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115579/what-is-the-difference-between-the-cryptography-and-encryption-tags) and as an overview of all the crypto related tags: [Cleanup cryptography related tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166924/cleanup-cryptography-related-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see with this is that decryption is not really possible or useful without encryption. And in many if not most occasions the encryption method is as likely the cause of any issues (and thus questions) as the decryption.

Furthermore, I do think that there are already enough tags that have to do with cryptography. In the end we should not so much worry about the exact meaning of the word. Instead we should be worried about the visibility of the questions (and thus answers). Having to check yet another tag is not going to help *me* for sure.

Finally, a question can only have 5 tags. As there are many questions that would merit both the encryption as well as the decryption tag, I'm afraid that users will run out of tag space.

---

For these reasons I've also nominated [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) (439 followers) to be a synonym of [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) (over 11K followers, about 25 times as many), even though both are not identical in a *linguistic* sense. There's just too many questions "flying under the radar" as I like to call it. Once in a few weeks I clean up those kind of tags, but I'd rather not and some users have to wait for weeks to get an answer.

---

The difference between [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography) and [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) on the other hand is entirely practical. Most questions that have to do only with encryption are correctly tagged with [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption) and most questions that have to do with anything else are tagged [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography). That's useful to me and both have enough followers to merit a split.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You've made [the same argument](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217994/should-decryption-tag-be-synonymous-with-encryption/218076?noredirect=1#comment706759_217994) as CodesInChaos regarding encryption being to blame for most decryption issues, which is likely true. Perhaps I would feel better if [tag:encryption] and [tag:decryption] where both synonyms of some word that encompasses them both. That way it won't feel like decryption has been trumped, in some sense. I'm not sure there is such a word, so perhaps I just have to get over it!

Comment: Eh, cipher? No, that's joking :) Even if there was another word, people would not use it. I agree with you that it does not feel right to use [tag:encryption] for [tag:decryption] but I'm pretty used to life's little surprises by now. We can only go to practical most of the time - and *that's* a bit strange for something that is entirely deterministic in nature too :P

Answer (score -3):

Encryption is useless without the consideration of decryption. It is in this sense that they are grouped.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption for example. It mentions both topics.

Comment: So encoding is useless without decoding? Decompilation is useless without compilation? Where would the synonyms end...?

Comment: No, decompilation is not a necessary step in a compilation process.

Comment: Nor is decryption a necessary step in encryption.

Comment: Round and round we go.

Comment: Why "round and round"? You provided an argument to why decompilation and compilation are not related and *the same argument* applies to encryption and decryption. Can you explain why it doesn't?